# HTML5 DIV flashes on tap

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

When receving an onclick event from a DIV as a result of a tap on the iPad, The DIV automatically flashes to a dark color to give the user feedback for the tap. Is there any way to prevent this flash from occurring?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's because there are events on the element. Just set:

```
div {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: was pulling my hair out. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding a class for `div.stylename:active` ? give the background the same colour as the div.